# List all keys, excluding arrays

Tags: jq

I am trying to create a one size fits all jq command to dump out all keys containing data, eg number,string,null,boolean

When it hits a value that is an array, I don't want the array name printed, rather it should look inside the array and extract the key names from inside the array.

The example output would be like such...

```
coord.lon
coord.lat
weather.0
weather.0.id
weather.0.main
weather.0.description
weather.0.icon
base
```

I have the following bit that works, but it returns the parent keys which are arrays and I don't need those, just the subkeys.

```
jq -r 'paths | map(.|tostring)|join(".")' weather.json
```

Can anyone provide any help?  I'm struggling pretty badly.

Example json

```
  {
  "coord": {
    "lon": -90.85,
    "lat": 38.8
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 501,
      "main": "Rain",
      "description": "moderate rain",
      "icon": "10d"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 38.19,
    "pressure": 1020,
    "humidity": 100,
    "temp_min": 36,
    "temp_max": 39.99
  },
  "visibility": 4023,
  "wind": {
    "speed": 4.7,
    "deg": 330
  },
  "rain": {
    "1h": 1.82
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 75
  },
  "dt": 1572448290,
  "sys": {
    "type": 1,
    "id": 4178,
    "country": "US",
    "sunrise": 1572438477,
    "sunset": 1572476760
  },
  "timezone": -18000,
  "id": 0,
  "name": "Wentzville",
  "cod": 200
}
```

Comment: why should `"coord"` itself be skipped? it's not an array

Comment: You are correct, should have been more specific... I am looking for any fields that contain data...   I believe coord is an object, so I would want the fields that are beneath coord.

Answer (score 2):

You could delete arrays first, e.g.:

```
del(.[] | select(type=="array"))
```

To only keep objects do something like this:

```
<infile.json jq -r '
del(.[] | select(type!="object")) |
paths                             |
map(tostring)                     |
select(length==2)                 |
join(".")
'
```

Output:

```
coord.lon
coord.lat
main.temp
main.pressure
main.humidity
main.temp_min
main.temp_max
wind.speed
wind.deg
rain.1h
clouds.all
sys.type
sys.id
sys.country
sys.sunrise
sys.sunset
```

### Edit

Perhaps you want a combination of the two answers?

```
paths(scalars)      |
select(length >= 2) |
map(tostring)       |
join(".")
```

Output:

```
coord.lon
coord.lat
weather.0.id
weather.0.main
weather.0.description
weather.0.icon
main.temp
main.pressure
main.humidity
main.temp_min
main.temp_max
wind.speed
wind.deg
rain.1h
clouds.all
sys.type
sys.id
sys.country
sys.sunrise
sys.sunset
```

Comment: Thanks @Thor
That is almost spot on!  However, it is chopping
weather.0.id
weather.0.main
weather.0.description
weather.0.icon

which all have data.

Comment: Thank you so much!  This is absolutely perfect!  You taught me something new today!  Appreciate it more than you know!!

Answer (score 1):

this is working :

`jq -r 'paths(scalars) | map(.|tostring)|join(".")' weather.json`

result

```
coord.lon
coord.lat
weather.0.id
weather.0.main
weather.0.description
weather.0.icon
base
main.temp
main.pressure
main.humidity
main.temp_min
main.temp_max
visibility
wind.speed
wind.deg
rain.1h
clouds.all
dt
sys.type
sys.id
sys.country
sys.sunrise
sys.sunset
timezone
id
name
cod
```